# what Graphical DSP programming tools are there for ASIO4ALL?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, soundcard

Many years ago I had a PCI sound card (I think it was some kind of SoundBlaster but not sure, this was maybe 15 years ago) with a 5 1/4 disk sized front panel with various ins and out.

I remember using ASIO4All but there was also a graphical component where I could program the DSP directly by creating a visual circuit and add effects and other features, and I used this to create a multitrack studio with talkback capabilities to the artists.

But I can't for the life of me remember what it was, or find anything similar on the webs.

is the 10k DSP still a thing?  If not, what is the modern-day equivalent, and is the visual programming still available for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You will have better chances of getting your question answered on the dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, didn't know there was one. Thanks for info.

Comment: Question has been answer in the other place. The answer was SBAudigy with KX Project.